# DataBase multiple issues ,0x80131904 ,EventID 3760 ,5586 + Cannot open database

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

we faced an problem in the our clustered database instance , after our I/S team fixed it , our sharepoint environment facing multiple errors all of them goes around DB .

1. Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131904 :
   This error is about DB size is full , the content DB shows that there is 10 mb is free , and also I am setting it to auto growth. and physical driver have more than 20 gb free.
2. Event 3760 (SharePoint Foundation) of severity 'Critical' occurred 1 more time(s) and was suppressed in the event log
   This error is about DB corruption , I run the repair command

   get-spcontentdatabase

   $cdb.repair($false)

this returned me false , I dont know if this fixed or not.

3. Event 5586 (SharePoint Foundation) of severity 'Error' occurred 540 more time(s) and was suppressed in the event log.
   this related to Named Pipes , I doubled checked on the SQL nod that this option is enabled , I searched on the cluster configuration I did not found any there.
4. tried to run farm backup also returned cant read from DB error
5. I just wanted to make sure that my problem is only on the already created database , so i tried to add new content database I got this error "Could not connect to SQLSVR using integrated security: SQL server at SQLSVR has an unsupported version 10.50.1617.0. Please refer to "http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=230806" for information on the minimum required SQL Server versions and how to download them. " problem is this farm was working fine for more than 6 months
6. SQL Database 'SharePoint_Config_Intranet_SP15_Ent' on SQL Server instance 'SQLSVR' not found. Additional error information from SQL Server is included below.
   Cannot open database "SharePoint_Config_Intranet_SP15_Ent" requested by the login. The login failed.
   Login failed for user 'Domain\UserName'.

I tried to login from the same server to the same SQL server using using the same windows credential its worked.

here is also couple of error i found ,,

> **Unknown SQL Exception 102 occurred. Additional error information from SQL Server is included below.
>
> Incorrect syntax near '('. Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'.
>   If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces
>   clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement
>   must be terminated with a semicolon.

**The OpsMgr Connector connected to sce1.DOMAINNAME.local, but the connection was closed immediately after authentication occurred.  The most likely cause of this error is that the agent is not authorized to communicate with the server, or the server has not received configuration.  Check the event log on the server for the presence of 20000 events, indicating that agents which are not approved are attempting to connect.

**A certificate validation operation took 15010.5266 milliseconds and has exceeded the execution time threshold.  If this continues to occur, it may represent a configuration issue.  Please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=246987 for more details.

**A database error occurred. Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider Code: -2 occurred 0 time(s) Description:  Error ordinal: 1 Message: Connection Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed during the post-login phase.  The connection could have timed out while waiting for server to complete the login process and respond;

I tried to restore content data base from yesterday , same errors.

sorry for the ling post ,, 
any help ? any idea ?

Comment: forget to mention , our SQL is 2008 R2 SP1 , and our is sharePoint 2013  Enterprise

Answer (score 0):

in case anyone face this issue ,, 
one of the infrastructure has installed SP RTM version
this is the steps that solved the issue ,,

1)turn off SP services and IIS server

2)install SP3 on the SQL servers.

3)turn on SP services and IIS

4) run the configuration wizard..

every thing worked except the meta service DB , i just re-create them since we dont use it that much ..